# Python file creation issue

Tags: python, file, creation

I want to create calculator using Python language (already created the directory) and wondering how to understand what does it actually mean by "file creation" task.

I tried searching "file creation for python" but didn't manage to find anything.

```
Step 1: Create a File for the Calculator
The first step covers the following skills:

Directory creation.
File creation. <--
File editing in a text editor.
```

Comment: please clarify your question. What are you trying to achive and what's the issue

Comment: Do you mean to create a file to put Python code into? You open your favorite editor/IDE, choose "New file ..." and create `my_first_program.py` (or any other name that ends in `.py`) in that directory of yours.

Comment: `with open("path/to/file.txt", "w") as f: f.write("text to write to file")`

Answer (score 2):

I think what is being asked for is for you to create the .py file that will contain your code.

In Windows you can create a file through file explorer by doing the steps defined here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-create-a-new-text-file-using-file-explore/118e12c3-8969-440e-b12c-0e0234db24eb

Just make sure to make the extension .py

You can also create files through the Windows command prompt by navigating to the directory you would like to create the file and using the following command:

```
type NUL > Example.py
```

Here is the Linux command:

```
touch Example.py
```

Most text editors have ways of creating new files. Depending on which text editor the guide is wanting you to use, you can find out how to create a new file through that specific program.